# How to set button color by checking all the database values in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to make a like/upvote system for my micro blogging site (without using redux). I have created a database star.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StarSchema = new Schema({
  toggled: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: false
  },
  postId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Star = mongoose.model("Star", StarSchema);
```

In StarButton.jsx file, I have a star button component. If a particular user has pressed this button, than a post request is made to the star database. Now I want to show the color red if the user has clicked the button permanently. 
What I am doing is, I am using a map function to check if if the user and post id is present in the star database and set color equal to red by updating the state value. 
I want to make it clear that different users would have different post button which they have toggled.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faStar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../actions/authActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class StarButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      btnColor: "#bcc1c6",
      toggled: false,
      postId: "",
      userId: "",
      starCount: 0,
      starData: []
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    this.setState({
      postId: this.props.postId,
      userId: user.id
    });

    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/stars")
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then( data => { this.setState({ starData: data }) } )
  }

  btnToggled = () => {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const starPackage = {
      toggled: true,
      postId: this.props.postId,
      userId: user.id
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/stars",
    {
      toggled: starPackage.toggled,
      postId: starPackage.postId,
      userId: starPackage.userId
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    }
    )
    .then("Star toggle submitted by " + starPackage.userId)
    .catch(console.log(err => "Error !!" + err));
  };

  starCount(){
    console.log("star count function gives " + this.props.postId);
  }

  starCheck(postId, userId) {
    const {user} = this.props.auth;
    console.log("Match" + this.props.postId, user.id);
    console.log("with " + postId, userId);
    if( postId.toString() === this.props.postId.toString() && userId.toString() === user.id.toString()){
       this.setState({ btnColor: "red" })   // Here I am setting the state value
      return "red"
    }

  }

  render() {
    const starColor = this.state.starData.map(star => ( this.starCheck(star.postId, star.userId) ));

      console.log("Star color issss " + starColor);
    return (
      <div>


        <button
          style={{ color: this.state.btnColor }}
          className="btn btn-light"
          onClick={this.btnToggled}
        >
          {" "}
          <span>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
            <span> {this.state.stars} </span>
            <p style = {{ fontSize: "small" }}>24</p>
          </span>

        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


StarButton.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser }
)(StarButton);
```

But I am facing the following error

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
starCheck
src/component/StarButton.jsx:68

  65 |   console.log("Match" + this.props.postId, user.id);
  66 |   console.log("with " + postId, userId);
  67 |   if( postId.toString() === this.props.postId.toString() && userId.toString() === user.id.toString()){
> 68 |      this.setState({ btnColor: "red" })
     | ^  69 |     return "red"
  70 |   }
  71 |
```

Is there a work around this method because my code/logic seems a bit shabby (I am a newbie).

Comment: You're calling `starCheck` inside `render()`. `starCheck` updates `state`, which causes a re-render. And so on, ad infinitum. You need to remove anything from `render()` that can potentially call `setState`. All `render()` does is turn the current state into HTML, it has no business messing with it.

Comment: maybe you could put your starcheck method inside the .then: 
`.then((resp) => starCheck(starPackage.postId,starPackage.userId)`

Comment: @chrisG you mean I should map the components outside the render method in another function ?

Comment: @rebecca .then would follow the map method ? I am a bit confused

Comment: i'm not even sure what you're trying to do with the map, since your not using it anywhere? and i meant to put it inside the .then() inside your btnToggle function

Comment: No, `map()` is perfectly fine to use inside `render()`. But you cannot *change* the state of the app inside `render()`. State changes can only happen inside event handlers or liveCycle functions. In other words: any operations you need to perform on data or the state must be handled elsewhere; you need to write your components in a way that at render-time, all information is already available in `state`.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are trying to 1. load all stars into your state 2. check all stars for whether they match the current post and user 3. turn state.btnColor "red" if a match is found 4. render the red star. This approach is not suitable at all. --- The proper way is to either a) load all stars in the app component and pass the color as a prop or b) make an API request that includes the stars postID and userID, set `state.btnColor` based on the reply c) use the color in the `render()` function.

Comment: Here's an example approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-bassi-8gjqd

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the color value to the state, you'd just compute it in render:

```
 starCheck = (postId, userId) => {
    const {user} = this.props.auth;

    if( postId.toString() === this.props.postId.toString() && userId.toString() === user.id.toString()){
       return "red"
    }

     return this.state.btnColor
  }
```

and then in render:

```
        <button
          style={{ color: this.starCheck(this.props.postId, this.props.auth.user.id) }}
          className="btn btn-light"
          onClick={this.btnToggled}
        >
```

Comment: Did not work. It only sets the button color to grey.. I think because the loop/map is resting the value. When I console log starColor I get `Star color issss #bcc1c6,#bcc1c6,#bcc1c6,red,red,#bcc1c6,#bcc1c6,#bcc1c6,#bcc1c6,red,#bcc1c6`